# Hybrid intel nvidia laptop with two 4k monitors

Tags: drivers, nvidia, display

I was hoping someone here could help me. I have a laptop (hp spectre 360 15"). It has intel gpu on board the motherboard, and a geforce mx150 card. I am running ubuntu 19.04. I have a laptop dock (cable matters thunderbolt 3 dock) that attaches via thunderbolt and has 1 hdmi out and 1 usb-c out ( for monitor ). Each of my monitors work separately but I can't get the system to use both of them. When I run xrandr I see both monitors and they both say connected.
I don't know where the problem is. I'd be happy to provide any diagnostic material. I just don't know many commands. 
Thank you
Raif

Comment: Thunderbolt docks are notorious for having problems. I use a direct USB-C thunderbolt to HDMI adapter and only problem was 24Hz at 4K. I bought the new model and got 54 Hz which was much easier on eyes.

Comment: I use the USB-C thunderbolt to HDMI cable as well.  My one 4k ( which ever one runs ) is at 30Hz I'm a developer so I'm not watching videos or playing games.  So I don't notice much difference. I just want my other monitor to work.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the cable matters thunderbolt 3 dock will only display one monitor for the hp spectre 360.  Found that gem buried in the knowledge base.